# Getting the error "Cannot find the object 'XXX', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." logged as SA in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to deny permission to perform a select to an user in SQL Server 2016 and it gives me no permission even if I am logged as SA.

> $/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U USER_TEST_0 -P ****** -d
>   TEST_DB -Q 'CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (TEST_COLUMN INT)'
>       Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Server test-server, Line 1
>
> There is already an object named 'TEST_TABLE' in the database.
>
> $/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -I -S localhost -U SA -P ****** -d TEST_DB -Q 'DENY SELECT ON TEST_TABLE TO USER_TEST_0'
>       Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Server test-server, Line 1
>
> Cannot find the object 'TEST_TABLE', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: Maybe the existing object isn't a table or view. Check `SELECT type, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE lower(name) = 'test_table';` for clues.

Comment: You are trying to deny select on anything or just one table? Also, what is the default schema for USER_TEST_O, because maybe the TEST_TABLE exists in the USER_TEST_O's default schema?

Comment: Are you sure that you are executing the script against the correct database? Have you seen any results with Select * from table_name

Comment: @stickybit I performed that query using the SA user and the result is: type 'U' type desc 'USER_TABLE'

Comment: @FembotDBA I am trying to deny select on just one table.

Comment: @CR241 Yes, when I perform the select with the user USER_TEST_0, the select is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a bit of research.
Looks like to access the table, I need to specify the schema. I made a query to see the schema of a table that looks like:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -I -S localhost -U SA -P ****** -d TEST_DB -Q "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables"
```

And turns out the schema was USER_TABLE_0.

So the correct way for denying SELECT is:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -I -S admin:localhost -U SA -P ****** -d TEST_DB -Q 'DENY SELECT ON [USER_TEST_0].TEST_TABLE TO USER_TEST_0'
```

Comment: So basically what I suggested was correct in my comment. I should have made an answer out of it. :)